# Return http 500 with Slim framework

Tags: php, slim

If somethings goes bad in my API i want to return a http 500 request.

```
$app = new Slim();
$app->halt(500);
```

It still return a http 200.

If i run this code:

```
    $status = $app->response()->status(); 
    echo $status; //Here it is 200
$status = $app->response()->status(500);
    echo $status; //Here it is 500
```

it stills give me a http 200

Answer (score 6):

The `$app->response()->status(500);` is correct, see the docs [here](http://docs.slimframework.com/pages/response-status/).

Check to make sure you're calling `$app->run();` after setting the status, this will prepare and output the response code, headers and body.

**Edit**, make sure you define a route or Slim will output the 404 response, this works:

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->response()->status(500);

$app->get('/', function () {
    // index route
});

$app->run();
```

Comment: $app = new Slim();
  $app->response()->status(500);
  $app->run();It stills return a http 200 in fiddler, but the web view is now 404. Why ?

Comment: Check the response code using HTTPLiveHeaders or Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools (F12).

Comment: It returns http 200 in fiddler and in Firebug.

Comment: Try removing any `echo` statements or other output and re-run the code.

Comment: It is already removed. Still return http 200 in both fiddler and Firebug. Does it work for you?

Comment: @rubin try my example code (works), if you don't define a route it will give the 404.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone still has this issue here is what I ended up doing:

Setup an error handler

```
    $app->error(function (Exception $exc) use ($app) {
       // custom exception codes used for HTTP status
       if ($exc->getCode() !== 0) {
          $app->response->setStatus($exc->getCode());
       }

       $app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       echo json_encode(["error" => $exc->getMessage()]);
    });
```

then, anytime you need to return a particular HTTP status throw an Exception with the status code included:

```
    throw new Exception("My custom exception with status code of my choice", 401);
```

(Found it on the Slim forum)

Answer (score 2):

If you have to push header after $app->run(), you can always rely on the header php function:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 401 Anonymous not allowed');
```

Comment: No, I've defined some routes, for example:
    $rest->post('/path', function () use ($rest, $variable){ 
     ...
      if(something wrong) {
         header('HTTP/1.1 400 JSON invalid');
         exit();
      }
    }

Comment: This worked for me when Slim's `status()` and `setStatus()` failed to change the status code. Thanks! For others, note that since PHP 5.4 you can use [http_response_code](http://php.net/http_response_code) like so: `http_response_code(500);`

Answer (score 0):

Slim framework v2 [wiki status](http://docs.slimframework.com/response/status/)

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
  $app->response()->setStatus(500);
  $app->response()->setBody("responseText");  
  return $app->response();
});

$app->run();
```

or

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
  $app->halt(500, "responseText");
});
```