# Using entomb/slim-json-api with other middleware

Tags: php, json, api, slim

I am relatively new to PHP, which might well prove to be the main problem here - I get the feeling I'm missing something somewhat fundamental about PHP internals that would either make solving this straightforward, or make it glaringly obvious why I am wasting my time!...

Basically in the following Slim API code I would like the exception handling added by the excellent [entomb/slim-json-api](https://github.com/entomb/slim-json-api) middleware to also apply to the subsequent myMiddleware. As implemented below, it only seems to handle failures generated in the route code...

(PHP v 5.4.17)

```
$ php composer.phar info
entomb/slim-json-api dev-master c11e001 Slim extension to implement fast JSON API's
slim/slim            2.6.2              Slim Framework, a PHP micro framework
```

API code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Slim\Middleware;

class myMiddleware extends Middleware
{
    public function call()
    {
        $uri_array = explode('/', $this->app->request->getResourceUri());
        $env = $this->app->environment;

        if($uri_array[2] == 98) {
            throw new \Exception("User $uri_array[2], you are not even welcome in middleware!");
        } else {
            $body = array('user_from_middleware' => $uri_array[2]);
            $env['slim.input'] = json_encode($body);
        }

        $this->next->call();
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->view(new \JsonApiView());
$app->add(new \JsonApiMiddleware());
$app->add(new myMiddleware());

$app->get('/user/:id', function($id) use ($app) {
    if ($id == 99) {
        throw new \Exception("User $id, you are not welcome!");
    } else {
        $body = json_decode($app->request->getBody());
        $body->msg = "User $id welcome to my API!";
        $app->render(200,(array) $body);
    }
});
```

Here's a request that misses both Exceptions:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8082/test.php/user/1
{"user_from_middleware":"1","msg":"User 1 welcome to my API!","error":false,"status":200}
```

...this one fires the Exception in route, showing that the JsonApiMiddleware is working:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8082/test.php/user/99
{"msg":"ERROR: User 99, you are not welcome!","error":true,"status":500}
```

...but when this one fires the Exception in myMiddleware the API returns nothing:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8082/test.php/user/98
$
```

...and I can see from the log that the exception was definitely thrown:

```
[Mon Nov  7 21:54:08 2016] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'User 98, you are not even welcome in middleware!' in /path/to/test.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1302): myMiddleware->call()
#1 /path/to/test.php(42): Slim\Slim->run()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /path/to/test.php on line 14
```

What am I missing? Apologies again if this is a tedious question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should not `$this->next->call()` in `MyMiddlware` if an exception is thrown?..

```
class myMiddleware extends Middleware
{
    public function call()
    {
        $uri_array = explode('/', $this->app->request->getResourceUri());
        $env = $this->app->environment;

        if($uri_array[2] == 98) {
            throw new \Exception("User $uri_array[2], you are not even welcome in middleware!");
        } else {
            $body = array('user_from_middleware' => $uri_array[2]);
            $env['slim.input'] = json_encode($body);
            $this->next->call(); // call next callable only if exception was not thrown
        }
    }
}
```

*Seems like you're using Slim v 2.*, but this is what I'd do in Slim 3.5.*

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Georgy! I just tried moving the next->call() into the else{} block as suggested and I'm afraid it still doesn't behave as I was hoping (although the response is slightly different - I get 3 spaces and a line feed).

Comment: Did you find the answer helpful?

Comment: (Sorry, got sidetracked before the 5min comment edit timeout)..(To be clear, I was hoping/expecting the exception to be handled by the `$app->error` code in `JsonApiMiddleware.__construct()`, thereby causing a JSON formatted status 500 to be returned)

Comment: Then you can create a custom error handler, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26682395/6850820). Just remember that [according to the docs](http://docs.slimframework.com/errors/500/), custom error handlers are only invoked if application debugging is disabled.

Comment: Yeah, thanks again Georgy but I already tried that too, and thats also exactly what happens in `JsonApiMiddleware.__construct()`, if you look [here](https://github.com/entomb/slim-json-api/blob/master/jsonAPI/JsonApiMiddleware.php#L47). I've tried putting `$app->error` code in `myMiddleware.__construct()` and in main and in all possible locations after `$app = new \Slim\Slim()`. Its like the error handler in JsonApiMiddleware is preventing any error handler working, even when I define one inside myMiddleware...